# A nearly lookalike strindex implementation of K&R found substring when there was no substring

Tags: c

I was trying to implement the K&R strindex program. User will be asked to enter a line, if the line contains the string "boi" in it, program will confirm that the line contained the pattern. The problem is, program confirms **some** other string/strings.

If i enter "şgb" it will confirm that it contains the string "boi". So far, it only happens with "şgb".

https://onlinegdb.com/SyeeO0mzH

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE_LENGTH 100

char pattern[] = "boi";

int get_line(char line[], int maxlength);
int str_index(char str[], char substr[]);

int main() {
  char line[MAXLINE_LENGTH];

  while(get_line(line, MAXLINE_LENGTH) > 0) {
    if(str_index(line, pattern) >= 0) {
      printf("%s", line);
      printf("Pattern found above line\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int get_line(char line[], int maxlength){
  int index = 0, character;

  while(--maxlength > 0 && (character = getchar()) != EOF && character != '\n') {
    line[index++] = character;
  }

  if(character == '\n') {
    line[index++] = character;
  }

  line[index] = '\0';

  return index;
}

int str_index(char str[], char substr[]) {
  int i, j, k;

  for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    for(j = i, k = 0; substr[k] != '\0' && str[j] == substr[k]; j++, k++) ;

    if(k > 0) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

```
boi
boi
Pattern found above line
```

```
fbajdobadşgbadf
fbajdobadşgbadf
Pattern found above line
```

```
şgb
şgb
Pattern found above line
```

Comment: That string doesn't look like plain ASCII chars to me...

Comment: Also just at a glance the second for loop in str_index looks wrong - won't it return even if just the first character matches? After one matching character k will be 1 so you'll return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `str_index`, if **any** character in `str` is the first character in `substr`, then, when `i` is such that `str[i]` is that character, `substr[j] == substr[k]` will be true in the first iteration of `for(j = i, k = 0;…`, and `k` will be incremented. When that loop ends, `k > 0` is true, and `return i;` will be executed.

You need to modify the code so that it returns `i` only if **all** the characters in `substr` have been matched.